# Edit value in nested Association

Tags: associations

Here is a simplified version of my problem.

I have a nested Association.

```
worksheet = <|"startDate" -> 
   DateObject[{2017, 8, 10}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
  "eventList" -> {
    <|"eventName" -> "Thursday Stratified 49r Pairs", 
     "eventTotal" -> 336.`|>,
    <|"eventName" -> "Thursday Aftt Side Pairs",
      "eventTotal" -> 240.`|>}|>
```

Below are the Keys

```
Keys[worksheet]
(* {"startDate", "eventList"} *)
```

I have a function to fix the names in the `eventList` when they are bad. Simplified function is:

```
fixName[name_] := Module[
  {
   newName = name
   },
  newName = StringReplace[newName, "Aftt" -> "Aft"]
  ]
```

Below is the input name and the corrected name for the second entry in  `eventList`

```
worksheet["eventList"][[2]]["eventName"]
(* "Thursday Aftt Side Pairs" *)

fixName[worksheet["eventList"][[2]]["eventName"]]
(* "Thursday Aft Side Pairs" *)
```

I want to `Scan` the names in `eventList` and replace the corrected name with the input name.

I want to replace `worksheet` with the edited version.

Here is what I tried:

```
worksheet = Function[wsIn,
  Module[
   {
    len = Length[wsIn["eventList"]],
    wsOut = wsIn
    },
   Scan[
    (wsOut["eventList"][[#]]["eventName"] = 
       fixName[wsOut["eventList"][[#]]["eventName"]]) &,
    Range[len]
    ];
   wsOut
   ]
  ][worksheet]
```

However, this produces an error

```
Association::setps: <|eventName->Thursday Stratified 49r Pairs,
                     eventTotal->336.|> in the part assignment
is not a symbol.
```

Need help with this code.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, it is typically easier to just return a modified object instead of trying to do in-place modifications. For instance, this should work in for the case at hand, while being significantly more readable: `Query["eventList", All, "eventName", fixName]@worksheet`

Comment: Why not use `ReplacePart`? You can also use `wsOut[["eventList", #, "eventName"]] = ...` but that'll be less efficient

Comment: @LukasLang it's not even really an in-place modification since `worksheet` isn't held on input.

Comment: how about `fiXName[key_,repl_]:= Replace[#,<|key -> v_, y___|> :><|key -> StringReplace[v, repl],y|> ,All]&; fiXName["eventName",  "Aftt" -> "Aft"]@worksheet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [AssociateTo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociateTo.html) to modify the inner association in the worksheet, i.e.:

```
Function[wsIn,
  Module[{len = Length[wsIn["eventList"]], wsOut = wsIn},
   Scan[
    AssociateTo[
      wsOut["eventList"][[#]], 
      "eventName" -> fixName[wsOut["eventList"][[#]]["eventName"]]
      ] &,
    Range[len]];
   wsOut]
  ][worksheet]
```

Comment: `AssociateTo` is exactly what I needed. Thank you sakra.